# Reading multiple Div's with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#-4.0, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to pull the data from 2 different Div's but I can only get the data from the first Div (cities). I have the code setup as an example from a wiki page where all li elements from the `H2 id = cities` and `id = Other_destinations:`

```
var xpathData = "//h2[span/@id='Cities' or @id='Other_destinations']" + "/following-sibling::ul[1]" + "/li";
```

I then write whatever was in the the li's to a text document.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> destinations = new List<string>();
        var xpathData = "//h2[span/@id='Cities' or @id='Other destinations']" + "/following-sibling::ul[1]" + "/li";

        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        String html = web.DownloadString("http://wikitravel.org/en/Germany");

        hap.HtmlDocument doc = new hap.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"C:\path\testText.txt"))
        { 
            foreach (hap.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpathData)) 
            {

            string all = node.InnerText;

            //Writes to text file
            write.WriteLine(all);
            }
        }

      }
```

A note about the `'hap'` , I had to use using `hap = HtmlAgilityPack;` due to some strange conflict.

Thanks for any help/suggestions/direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistyping with the second id in your original code:

```
var xpathData = "//h2[span/@id='Cities' or span/@id='Other_destinations']" + "/following-sibling::ul[1]" +
                        "/li";
```

It's the code I used :

```
var destinations = new List<string>();
var xpathData = "//h2[span/@id='Cities' or span/@id='Other_destinations']" + "/following-sibling::ul[1]" +
                        "/li";

var webClient = new WebClient();
var html = webClient.DownloadString("http://wikitravel.org/en/Germany");

// to control the encoding 
var doc = new HtmlDocument
{
    OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

doc.LoadHtml(html);

using (var write = new StreamWriter("testText.txt"))
{
   foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpathData))
   {
       var all = node.InnerText;

       //Writes to text file
       write.WriteLine(all);
   }

}
```

Comment: Nice catch! Unfortunately, it did not totally solve the issue. Now it only goes out and grabs the first li in the Div...

Comment: I have tested your code and works fine in my machine. I going to edit my answer with my code. Please run it.

Comment: Well, you are correct. This code does work just fine. I have since altered the code that this part is being used in and it only grabs the first li from the 'Other_destinations' Div... Must be getting tripped up somewhere else... Thank you.

Comment: I believe the issue is in the WikiTravel code formatting. Thanks again!

Comment: You could in the WebClient specify the Encoding if you want also

Comment: For some reason in wiki there are multiple ul's with only 1 li in each. Any clue how to handle this using HAP and the current formula (using HAP) or would this be a back to the drawing board affair?

Comment: Please explain me better I don't understand what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

*Updated with a working solution*
So now the issue is that some countries have strange markup. Most Div's are setup as:

```
<h2>
<span id="cities"></span>
</h2>
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
...
</ul>
<h2>
...
</h2>
```

But, when I mentioned in the comments that it was only pulling only the first li from the Other_destinations div, what was happening is that the current script is only looking at the first ul and then the li's in the div. So the markup on that particular countries page is like this:

```
<h2>
<span id="Other_destinations"></span>
</h2>
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
...
</ul>
<h2>
<span id="Get_in"></span>
</h2>
```

*UPDATED working code*

```
var xpathData = "//ul[preceding-sibling::h2[span/@id='Cities' or span/@id='Other_destinations'] and following-sibling::h2[span/@id='Get_in']]" + "/li";
```

This query works to get only 2 sections of information from a web page in HTML formatting described above. An important note is that the text needs to be encoded, or it will print to text with '-' as 'â€”'. I added this encoding for the web client:

```
var web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
String html = string.Empty;
html = //get URL's
```

And this coding for the document:

```
var doc = new hap.HtmlDocument
{
    OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Comment: You can use something like this : `xpath="//div[@id='div']/child::ul/li"`, I recommend you read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp), really is very useful. Please if you have more questions, post it to answer correctly. I hope this help you

Comment: Oh, sorry about the answer. I was going to reformat it when I reached a solution. I tried to use child but it only returns an empty text document.

Comment: Look , post this question and let me know in the comments to can show you my code, because here I can't post large code

Comment: @Vkt0r I have submitted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190747/getting-li-values-from-multiple-uls-using-htmlagilitypack-c-sharp). Thank you.

Comment: Above answer was reached from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190747/getting-li-values-from-multiple-uls-using-htmlagilitypack-c-sharp)