# Getting li values from multiple ul's using HtmlAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

This query works perfect for some countries like [Germany](http://wikitravel.org/en/Germany)

```
"//h2[span/@id='Cities' or span/@id='Other_destinations']" + "/following-sibling::ul[1]" + "/li";
```

Where the HTML is formatted as:

```
<h2>
<span id='Other_destination'></span>
</h2>
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

However, in a country like [Afghanistan](http://wikitravel.org/en/Afghanistan) the Div is formatted as such:

```
<h2>
    <span id='Other_destination'></span>
    </h2>
<ul
<li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

So the question becomes, how do I handle the event of a country like Afghanistan where `"/following-sibling::ul[1]" + :/li"` only gets the first ul in Div='Other_destinations'? I hope that getting a handle on this will help with the other exceptions and formatting issues that I will come across on my other countries. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code solve your problem :

```
var xpath = "//ul[preceding-sibling::h2[span/@id='Cities' or span/@id='Other_destinations'] and following-sibling::h2[span/@id='Get_in']]" + "/li";

var doc = new HtmlDocument
{
   OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

// You need to call a WebClient here and set to the html variable.    
var html = String.Empty;

doc.LoadHtml(html);

using (var write = new StreamWriter("testText.txt"))
{
    foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath))
    {
        var all = node.InnerText;

        //Writes to text file
        write.WriteLine(all);
     }
 }
```

The above XPath can be translated to :

- Select all the `ul` tags has between by a `h2[span/@id='Cities' or span/@id='Other_destinations']` and a `h2[span/@id='Get_in']]`

I see that in all the pages has a `span` tag with `id='Get_in'` in the final.

I hope it solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but the variable `html` is just the html that you want to parse nothing else. Give me the link and update in the question exactly what do you want to parse exactly ,starting with `h2`

Comment: Just tried this out and it solves the issue perfectly. I didn't realize you could set queries up as such and would not have gotten to that conclusion without your help. Your help is so greatly appreciated! Cheers!